Proving $f(x) \geq g(x)$ for all $x$ is equivalent to proving $f \geq g$ for certain $x$ if both functions satisfy certain properties
I made the following conjecture from this earlier question: Question Regarding the proof to $\text{dim}(K_n)\geq \log_2{\log_2{n}}$ as in Proofs from the Book.

Given monotonic functions $f(x),g(x)$ (either both increasing or both decreasing) defined on $\mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)$ is integral and $g(x)$ is continuously differentiable, suppose $g(x)$ takes on integer values iff. $x \in X=\{x_i\}$, with all $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $f(x)$ outputs only integer values, with its value staying the same for all $x\in [n,n+1)$ where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we claim that proving $g(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ would be equivalent to proving $g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x=x_i+1$.

For example, if $g(x)=\log_2\log_2x$ and $f(x)=\text{dim}(K_x)$, then if we want to prove $g(x)\leq f(x)$, it suffices for us to show that $g(x)\leq f(x)$ for all $x=2^{2^n}+1$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. (Why?)
Is this conjecture correct? How do I prove it?
Edit:
Bauval has given a counterexample, namely $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$ and $g(x)=x$. I claim that the example as given above related to dimensions and logarithms still holds, as suggested from Proofs from the Book. Is this true and can we strengthen our conditions to make the general claim true?

A counterexample is
$$g(x)=x,\quad f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

Oh that’s correct. Regarding my original question, why does the claim stand for $\log_2\log_2 x$ and $\text{dim}(K_x)$?
